# Using CSS to create three boxes with dividers and text centered within each box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a row of three boxes (columns), with dividers (vertical lines) between boxes 1 and 2, and boxes 2 and 3. The text would need to be centered within each box.

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    color: #00ADEF;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:23px;
}

p {
    margin-top:0;
}

.3colwrapper {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.colbox {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 210px;
    background:#DDD;
    padding:10px 40px;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="3colwrapper">
    <div class="colbox"><h2>Step One</h2>
        <p>Sign up</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colbox"><h2>Step Two</h2>
        <p>Verify</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colbox"><h2>Step Three</h2>
        <p>Participate</p>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Here's what I've worked up so far: http://cssdesk.com/YyjAr

Comment: Download the file and open it ina browser, it actually has 3 columns in a row. It might not be displayed in cssdesk!

Comment: Here it is in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Spvvv/ It's dependent on displaying in column on the width of the containing document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 h2 {
color: #00ADEF;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
/* [disabled]line-height:23px; */
}

p {

margin-top:0;
}

.3colwrapper {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.colbox {
float: left;
width: 210px;
background: #DDD;
border-right-width: medium;
border-right-style: solid;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 40px;
}
 p {
 text-align: center;
 }

<html>
<body>
<div class="3colwrapper">
<div class="colbox"><h2>Step One</h2>
<p>Sign up</p>
</div>
<div class="colbox"><h2>Step Two</h2>
<p>Verify</p>
</div>
<div class="colbox"><h2>Step Three</h2>
<p>Participate</p>
</div>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is close. We need to eliminate the third vertical line.

Comment: give the last one Pseudo class..like colbox:last and set the border left = none it wil happen as you waant

Answer (score 1):

```
  h2 {
color: #00ADEF;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
/* [disabled]line-height:23px; */
   }


p {
 margin-top:0;
}

.3colwrapper {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.colbox {
float: left;
width: 210px;
background: #DDD;
border-right-width: medium;
border-right-style: solid;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 40px;
border-right-color: #000;
}

.colbox1 {
float: left;
width: 210px;
background: #DDD;
border-right-width: medium;
border-right-style: solid;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 40px;
border-right-color: #000;
}

.colbox2 {
float: left;
width: 210px;
background: #DDD;

margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 40px;
border-right-color: #000;
  }
p {
text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>



<body>
<div class="3colwrapper">
  <div class="colbox"><h2>Step One</h2>
 <p>Sign up</p>
  </div>

 <div class="colbox1"><h2>Step Two</h2>
 <p>Verify</p>
</div>
<div class="colbox2"><h2>Step Three</h2>
<p>Participate</p>
</div>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now the third vertical line is removed..and remaining is the previous one

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original answer I think since it's a follow up on the comments from that.

Comment: I tried this approach but cannot get it to span the entire 930 in pixels. The three columns appear bunched together, with the content in boxes two and three pushed up against the border to its left. Plus the div after it, which has nothing to do with this wrapper, appears immediately to the right of the third box, instead of underneath it.

Comment: becuasue of borders it wil not cover span of 930...and u wnat to put them all in row..and by settign margins you can get out of pushhing of divs after each ..and if u want the third one to beneath just insert a spacer div or br

Comment: This issue was due to a line break issue in WordPress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://cssdesk.com/MZJ7f Is this what you want ?